# If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a polynomial of odd degree, then for every real $y$ there is a real $x$ such that $f(x)=y$

Tags: polynomials, provability

> Prove that if the function  $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is an odd degree polynomial, for every number $y ∈ \mathbb R$ there exists such a number $x ∈ \mathbb R$ that $f(x) = y$. Prove that this is not true for any even polynomial.

I have trouble with this proof. I don't know how to write it for any degree of polynomial. How can I correctly prove it?

Comment: Hint: $f$ is continuous, $f(-\infty)=\mp\infty$, $f(\infty)=\pm\infty$.

Comment: @LDM yes, I adited it.

Comment: The function $f(x) = |x|$ is not a polynomial at all (and thus in particular not an even degree polynomial). It is an *even function*, but this is a, while related, different notion.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, so it is a full prove. It's enought to write this conditions for odd and even polynomial, isn't it?

Comment: @MeesdeVries You are right. I'm wrong in this condition.

Comment: @Cezary.Sz: sorry, don't get what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**:

Let's assume for now that the leading coefficient of $f$ is positive (otherwise, we can just take the polynomial $-f$ and be in the same boat). Then, use the facts:

- $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = -\infty$
- $f$ is a continuous function

Using these two facts, try and prove:

1. There exists some $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x) > y$
2. There exists some $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x) < y$
3. There exists some $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = y$

Try and prove these $3$ things (*in order*!) and tell us how far you got and where you are perhaps still stuck.

Comment: Can you show me first prove. I don't know how exactly I should start.

Comment: @Cezary.Sz Use the first of the two facts I have written down. Look at the definitions of what $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$ **means**.

Comment: I think I understand $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$. So next step should be check $\infty > y$, $\infty < y$ and $\infty = y$?

Comment: @Cezary.Sz That's not what that means. Please look at your textbook. $\infty$ is **not** a number.